# Como calcular a idade de uma pessoa com JS, a partir da data de nascimento?

Tags: javascript

Como posso calcular a idade de uma pessoa em Javascript a partir da data de nascimento?

Tentei algo do tipo:

```
function idade(dia, mes, ano) {
   return new Date().getFullYear() - ano;
}

idade(11, 12, 1980); //  33
idade(15, 2, 2011);  // 2
idade(5, 31, 1993);  // 20
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

— **Pedro**: Oi, Maria. Quantos anos você tem?

— **Maria**: Pedro, eu nasci em 28 de fevereiro de 1990.

— **Pedro**: Então, já sei qual é a sua idade!

— **Maria**: Qual é?

— **Pedro**: Basta pegar o ano atual e subtrair pelo ano em que você nasceu. Logo, 2014 - 1990 = 24. Você tem 24 anos.

— **Maria**: Não, na verdade eu tenho 23 anos. Eu faço 24 dia 28 de fevereiro.

— **Maria**: Para calcular a idade, você subtrai o ano atual pelo ano de nascimento. Mas se ainda não passou da data de aniversário, você subtrai 1.

— **Pedro**: Ah, é. Esqueci desse detalhe!

---

```
function idade(ano_aniversario, mes_aniversario, dia_aniversario) {
    var d = new Date,
        ano_atual = d.getFullYear(),
        mes_atual = d.getMonth() + 1,
        dia_atual = d.getDate(),

        ano_aniversario = +ano_aniversario,
        mes_aniversario = +mes_aniversario,
        dia_aniversario = +dia_aniversario,

        quantos_anos = ano_atual - ano_aniversario;

    if (mes_atual < mes_aniversario || mes_atual == mes_aniversario && dia_atual < dia_aniversario) {
        quantos_anos--;
    }

    return quantos_anos < 0 ? 0 : quantos_anos;
}



console.log(idade(1980, 12, 11)); //  33

console.log(idade(2011, 2, 15));  // 2

console.log(idade(1993, 31, 5));  // 20
```

Comment: Essa narração ficou bem intuitivo e de fácil aprendizado, parabéns. :)
Respostas como essa devem ser agradecidas, obrigado.

Answer (score 17):

Sugiro comparar o mês e o dia do mês: se a data de hoje for maior ou igual a do nascimento (i.e. o aniversário já passou), então basta fazer a diferença entre os anos. Caso contrário, faça a diferença e subtraia `1`:

```
function idade(nascimento, hoje) {
    var diferencaAnos = hoje.getFullYear() - nascimento.getFullYear();
    if ( new Date(hoje.getFullYear(), hoje.getMonth(), hoje.getDate()) < 
         new Date(hoje.getFullYear(), nascimento.getMonth(), nascimento.getDate()) )
        diferencaAnos--;
    return diferencaAnos;
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/B469L/).

Answer (score 9):

Que tal calcular de uma forma bem mais minimalista? O cálculo com ms é altamente superior considerado o desempenho. Ex: Nasci em 17/12/1995. Então:

```js
function calcAge(dateString) {
  var birthday = +new Date(dateString);
  return ~~((Date.now() - birthday) / (31557600000));
}

console.log(calcAge("Thu Dec 17 1995 00:51:54 GMT-0300 (BRT)"));
```

Se o código for executado antes do dia 17/12/2015. Ainda terei 19 anos :P

A técnica utilizada se encontra em:
http://jsperf.com/birthday-calculation
E agradeço ao Caio Ribeiro por ter me mostrado

Answer (score 8):

Uma solução de apenas uma linha, calculando a partir da quantidade de dias:

```
// calcula a idade considerando os parâmetros 
// 'nascimento' e 'hoje' como objetos Date
function calculaIdade(nascimento, hoje){
    return Math.floor(Math.ceil(Math.abs(nascimento.getTime() - hoje.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365.25);
}
```

A lógica utilizada é a seguinte:

- `Math.abs(nascimento.getTime() - hoje.getTime())` - retorna a quantidade de milissegundos passados desde `nascimento` até `hoje`. A função `Math.abs` retorna o módulo da subtração, ou seja, transforma um número negativo em positivo e mantém o sinal de um positivo.
- `/ (1000 * 3600 * 24)` - calcula a quantidade de dias a partir da quantidade de milissegundos retornada na expressão anterior. Dividindo por 1000, temos a quantidade de segundos; a quantidade de segundos dividindo por 3600 temos a quantidade de horas (pois em 1 hora cabem 3600 segundos); e finalmente divide-se a quantidade de horas por 24, que teremos a quantidade de dias correspondente.
- `Math.ceil` - arredonda para cima o valor decimal da operação anterior, pois é considerado que se passou um dia mesmo que a quantidade de horas não dê 24 horas. Como por exemplo um bebê que nasceu ontem a noite, consideramos que na manhã de hoje já tenha 1 dia de vida.
- `/ 365.25` - finalmente, calculamos o ano dividindo o total de dias pelo total de dias que cabem em um ano. O número 365.25 é porque um ano possui aproximadamente 365 dias e 6 horas, que é igual a 365.25 dias. O ano bixesto vem desta diferença, pois a cada 4 anos, as 6 horas desconsideradas no calendário tornam-se 24 horas, ou seja mais um dia.
- `Math.floor` - arredonda para baixo a quantidade de anos. Pois, não importa se a pessoa faz aniversário amanhã e tem 25.999 anos, ela tem 25 anos.

Comment: +1 Interessante a sua sugestão. Acho que seria legal você explicar um pouco na sua resposta como funciona o cálculo (por exemplo, nem todo mundo vai entender que o 0.25 a mais no divisor para obter o resultado em anos se deve à contabilização dos anos bissextos). Uma boa explicação dá credibilidade à resposta e, potencialmente, te ajuda a ganhar mais votos positivos. :)

Comment: Adicionada a explicação do cálculo. Grato pela sugestão.

Comment: Creio que é uma aproximação razoável, mas ainda vai falhar em datas próximas aos anos múltiplos de `100` (onde as regras para ano bissexto mudam).

Answer (score 2):

Ola, adaptei o código do @Gabriel S. para aceitar data no padrão brasileiro.

```
function calcIdade(data) {
    var d = new Date,
        ano_atual = d.getFullYear(),
        mes_atual = d.getMonth() + 1,
        dia_atual = d.getDate(),
        split = data.split('/'),
        novadata = split[1] + "/" +split[0]+"/"+split[2],
        data_americana = new Date(novadata),
        vAno = data_americana.getFullYear(),
        vMes = data_americana.getMonth() + 1,
        vDia = data_americana.getDate(),
        ano_aniversario = +vAno,
        mes_aniversario = +vMes,
        dia_aniversario = +vDia,
        quantos_anos = ano_atual - ano_aniversario;
    if (mes_atual < mes_aniversario || mes_atual == mes_aniversario && dia_atual < dia_aniversario) {
        quantos_anos--;
    }
    return quantos_anos < 0 ? 0 : quantos_anos;
}
// calcIdade('02/01/1978') => 39
// calcIdade('03/09/1980') => 36
```

Answer (score -1):

let niver, resposta;

function myfuction() {

dateString = document.getElementById('ip1').value

niver = new Date(dateString);

idade = Math.floor((Date.now() - niver) / (31557600000));

```
if (idade > 18) { 
    resposta = "Você é maior de idade, possui mais de 18 anos."
} else if (idade < 18) {
    resposta = "Você não é maior de idade, possui menos de 18 anos."
}
```

document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = resposta
}

Dessa forma ja se encaixa com o html

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).