# Como comparar idade com data de nascimento em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, data

Estou com uma dúvida tremenda. Não me pergunte por quê, mas tenho que comparar a idade digitada com a data de nascimento digitada pra ver se elas batem mas não consigo.
Por favor, quem puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Comment: como é que a data é inserida?

Comment: Mostre como está seu código até agora.

Comment: converta a data inserida em idade.. então compare a idade inserida com o resultado da data..

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, você pode verificar subtraindo o ano de nascimento pelo ano atual, caso a data de nascimento informada não tenha passado ainda, subtraia 1.

Neste link tem um exemplo de parte da sua pergunta, a pessoa precisava saber a idade a partir da data de nascimento.

> [Como calcular a idade de uma pessoa com JS, a partir da data de nascimento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5160/como-calcular-a-idade-de-uma-pessoa-com-js-a-partir-da-data-de-nascimento)

Após descobrir a idade usando esta função, basta fazer um if simples comparando as idades.

Segue o exemplo http://jsfiddle.net/897d6btq/, espero que ajude. :)

Outra solução mais elegante é você construir uma Regex.

Comment: Oi Daniel, podes dar exemplos para a resposta ficar mais completa?

Comment: Amigo, editei a resposta com o exemplo, espero que ajude. :)