# input tipo data so aceitar data maior de 18 anos

Tags: php, javascript

Como faço para colocar uma condição dentro do input do tipo date para ele so aceitar datas maiores de 18 anos, estava pensando se não tem uma condição para travar o input para datas com mais de 18 anos, é para um formulário onde so maiores de 18 podem enviar o formulário.

```
<label for="txtData_Nasc">Data de nascimento:</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="txtData_Nasc" name="txtData_Nasc" required>
```

Comment: seria mais conveniente você deixar o campo "livre" e fazer a verificação em seu código comparando as datas, se o usuario for menor de idade você exibe uma mensagem.

Comment: Tem como fazer isso sem precisar atualizar a pagina?

Comment: com javascript sim.

Comment: Como eu faria? sou iniciante e estou começando nesta area agora.

Comment: Dê uma olhada [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5160/como-calcular-a-idade-de-uma-pessoa-com-js-a-partir-da-data-de-nascimento) @EvertonFigueiredo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elementos do tipo `<input date...` aceitam o atributo `max`, porém você precisará de alguma forma calcular a data mínima de nascimento com base na data atual para atribuir este valor, exemplo:

Tomando como base a data de hoje (23/03/2017) a data mínima deve ser (23/03/1999), portanto você deve colocar este valor no atributo min do elemento no formato `AAAA-MM-DD`.

```html
<form>
<label for="txtData_Nasc">Data de nascimento:</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="txtData_Nasc" name="txtData_Nasc" max="1999-03-23" required>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Para fazer o cálculo da data automaticamente como php neste caso:

```
<label for="txtData_Nasc">Data de nascimento:</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="txtData_Nasc" name="txtData_Nasc" max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-18 year')); ?>" required>
```

**[Exemplo cálculo data no Ideone](https://ideone.com/fYX04f)**

Comment: Nem um dos dois exemplos funcionaram aqui. :/

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo eu troquei o max por min :P, na verdade o atributo que deve ser utilizado é o max. veja se o exemplo funciona agora.

Comment: Obrigado esta funcionando 100% @abfurlan

Comment: Tem um problema, se o usuário digitar a idade ainda pega por exemplo ano 2000.

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo se digitar sim, porém se tentar enviar o formulário aparecerá uma mensagem, faça o teste no exemplo acima digite a data e clique em enviar.

Comment: Verdade, desculpe o incomodo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode efetuar a validação no cliente através do javascript, porém recomendo que além do cliente realize a validação também no servidor (PHP). No evento OnBlur do input você pode fazer a chamada da função que fará a validação.

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="txtData_Nasc" name="txtData_Nasc" onblur="validaIdade()">
```

para criar a função que valida a idade você poderá seguir o exemplo a seguir:
[Validação de idade javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5160/como-calcular-a-idade-de-uma-pessoa-com-js-a-partir-da-data-de-nascimento?noredirect=1&lq=1)