# Como Adicionar Idade no input

Tags: javascript, input

Tudo bem com vocês manos?!

Poderia me ajudar em uma situação.
Estou fazendo um formulário simples, nele tenho dois `inputs`, um deles é o de Data de Nascimento e o outro é Idade. O que estou querendo fazer é que quando eu digite a data de nascimento no primeiro `input` o segundo automaticamente puxe a Idade já calculada.

**Ex:** quando eu digitar no `Input` da  Data de Nascimento : **09/01/2001**
o `input` da Idade automaticamente me traga **18 anos** sem apertar nenhum botão

No meu código, atualmente já consigo puxar a idade calculada, seguindo o exemplo acima, meu `input` puxa **18**, porem eu não estou conseguindo fazer com que puxe **"18 anos"**. No caso eu desejo adiciona **"anos"** logo apos a idade que está puxando.

Segue o codigo:

**HTML**

```html
<form method="get" action="evento.php?cadastro=true">
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>DADOS GERAIS</legend>
             <p>Nome * <input type="text" name="nomecompleto" required="true">
                Sexo * <select name="sexo">
                 <option value="">Selecione...</option>
                 <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                 <option value="Feminino">Feminino</option>
             </select>
             Cpf * <input type="text" name="cpf" required="true">
            </p>
            <p>Data <input type="text" name="nascimento" id="data" style="width: 110px;" >
              Idade <input type="text" name="idade" id="idade" disabled style="width: 70px;">
            </p>
        </fieldset>
</div>
    </form>
```

**JS**

```js
 document.getElementById("data").addEventListener('change', function() {
  var data = new Date(this.value);
  if(isDate_(this.value) && data.getFullYear() > 1900)
      document.getElementById("idade").value = calculateAge(this.value);
});

function calculateAge(dobString) {
  var dob = new Date(dobString);
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
  var birthdayThisYear = new Date(currentYear, dob.getMonth(), dob.getDate());
  var age = currentYear - dob.getFullYear();
  if(birthdayThisYear > currentDate) {
    age--;
  }
  return age;
}

function calcular(data) {
  var data = document.form.nascimento.value;
  alert(data);
  var partes = data.split("/");
  var junta = partes[2]+"-"+partes[1]+"-"+partes[0];
  document.form.idade.value = (calculateAge(junta));
}

var isDate_ = function(input) {
        var status = false;
        if (!input || input.length <= 0) {
          status = false;
        } else {
          var result = new Date(input);
          if (result == 'Invalid Date') {
            status = false;
          } else {
            status = true;
          }
        }
        return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O termo `anos` não está sendo inserido por que você só está inserindo o valor numérico calculado no `input`:

> ```
> document.form.idade.value = (calculateAge(junta))
> ```

Para incluir o termo `anos`, você deve concatená-lo:

```
document.form.idade.value = (calculateAge(junta) + ' anos')
```

---

Fiz um exemplo funcional (um pouco mais simples) abaixo:

```js
// Função para calcular a idade com base na data de nascimento.
// Origem (SOpt): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5160/como-calcular-a-idade-de-uma-pessoa-com-js-a-partir-da-data-de-nascimento#answer-5162
function getAge(birth) {
  const current = new Date()
  let diff = current.getFullYear() - birth.getFullYear()

  if (
    new Date(current.getFullYear(), current.getMonth(), current.getDate()) <
    new Date(current.getFullYear(), birth.getMonth(), birth.getDate())
  )
    diff--

  return diff
}

// "Pegar" os elementos dos campos:
const birthField = document.querySelector('#birth')
const ageField = document.querySelector('#age')

// Calcular a idade sempre que o campo da data de nascimento for alterado:
birthField.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const date = new Date(event.target.value)

  // Note abaixo que estou concatenando a idade calculada com o termo "anos":
  ageField.value = getAge(date) + ' anos'
})
```

```html
<label>Nascimento:</label>
<input type="date" id="birth" />
<br /><br />
<label>Idade:</label>
<input type="text" id="age" readonly />
```

---

> **P.S.:** Pude perceber que você está usando o atributo `disabled` para impedir que o campo de idade seja editado. Por razões semânticas, prefira usar o atributo `readonly` neste caso, a não ser que você não queira que o valor de "idade" seja enviado ao servidor. :)
>
> Para saber mais, veja [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-ht).

Comment: Agradeço bastante pela ajuda. Sou meio novato na área de programação, não conhecia sobre o `readonly` irei focar em ler mais sobre as possibilidades que tenho. Obrigado por me fazer evoluir mais um passo nessa área.